# In Scratch, how do you copy a PART of a costume so that you can paste that object onto another costume?

Tags: copy-paste, mit-scratch

Lets say I have two backdrops. One is a forest with a panda in it. Another is a zoo cage. I want to copy the panda in the forest costume and paste it into the zoo one.

I would prefer not to redraw the panda because I want the panda to look EXACTLY the same. I'd also prefer not to duplicate the forest with the panda in it and then redraw the zoo backdrop around it (although its starting to look like this is my only option).

I tried everything and looked everywhere and can't seem to find a Scratch-platform way of doing it. I simply want to know if there is a way to copy and past a part of a costume (not the whole costume). If its possible, knowing how to do it would be great for future use as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to delete the forest in the forest backdrop but not the panda. Use the rubber to remove all colors and avoid the panda (if you want to keep the forest backdrop, just duplicate it before).

Now make sure that the panda and the zoo costumes are at the same type (Bitmap or Vectorial)
Then with the selection tool, select the panda and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on a Mac) to copy it. Go on the zoo costume and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) to paste it.

Move it where you want and resize it as you need.
If you need, you can redraw the cage above the panda.

Comment: Thank you. This solution works with the offline editor. But for some reason, the online scratch platform at mit.scratch.edu doesn't let you copy and paste between different costumes. I'll just export to my offline editor the next time this becomes a problem. Thanks again for responding.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the panda (or even a part of it) bitmap...
I don't think it is possible

If you created it in vector...
You are in for a chance!
How?
You can select the panda and press `Ctrl` + `C`. This will copy the panda. Then, go to your other backdrop and press `Ctrl` + `V` and the panda is in. This will paste the panda. Now, move the panda to the desired location.